# WPF Grouped ListBox bound to CollectionView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, wpf-controls, mvvm-light

I am trying to find a way to code a list of grouped users and be able to dynamically display their work that is assigned to them.  I have an Observable Collection (UsersOC) that is bound to a CollectionViewSource in my XAML (Defined in the Resources section of the User Control) like so:

```
       <CollectionViewSource x:Key="UserQueueList" Source="{Binding QueueList}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name"></PropertyGroupDescription>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="EmployeeNumber"/>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="SortOrder"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

So what I have is a list of all the users and their related work.

I have to represent every driver, with or without work, in a list (grouped by user name) and then their work.  If they have no work I need to show a  that says "Drop work here" which is a Drop zone which will add the work to their queue.  I have to have the control be a ListBox under the driver name, so it will look like this:

```
 --> Driver Name1
     - work 1
     - work 2
 --> Driver Name2
     Drop Work Here
 --> Driver Name3
     - work 1
     - work 2
     - work 3
```

the areas with the work items listed, again, are/should be list boxes and can be individually dragged and dropped (i have that portion of the code already).  Here is what I have so far:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TrailerCardQueueList}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Transparent" 
             Background="Transparent" Name="lvDriverQueueWork" Margin="10,0,10,0" Foreground="Black">
        <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold">
                                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].EmployeeNumber}"/>
                                <Run Text="-"/>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    //I figured I could hide/show the area here with the default drop zone if they have no work, but this doesn't work.
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Style>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="DROP TRAILER CARD HERE"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Grid">

                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Style>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What specifically is going wrong here?

Comment: this code puts a text block in under every single item, values or no values

Comment: Have you tried placing the style for your grid in `ItemsControl.Resources`? I don't think you style is being evaluated when used inside of the `Template`.